# Chaging the Font size of UITextView created programmatically in ViewDidLoad

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitextview

My app creates several UITextViews while it's loading , inside the viewDidLoad method, since i need them to be created while the app launches for being able to scroll between views and have them slide with the scrolled view. I tried to create a UIButton and assign it the functionality of changing the font size of the text inside the UITextView. However, since it's programmatically created within the viewDidLoad method i can't get access on them, nothing happens. I tried to create the UITextViews by using the storyboard but didn't get the needed the result so i can't change my creation methods. Also, it's not logical to recall the viewDidLoad method when i press the button since it has lots of methods defined in it and it will drain the CPU power to recall it each time i need to change the font size. Here is how i create the UITextViews:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {


    CGSize imageSize;
    imageSize.height = 693;
    imageSize.width = 512;
    self.scroll1.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    self.scroll1.maximumZoomScale = 1.0;
    self.scroll1.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,imageSize.width,imageSize.height);
    self.scroll1.scrollEnabled = YES;
    self.scroll1.contentSize = CGSizeMake(imageSize.width * imgs.count, imageSize.height );
    self.scroll1.pagingEnabled = YES;
    self.scroll1.bounces = false;
    self.scroll1.delegate = self;
    leftTextFieldsArray=[NSMutableArray array];
    rightTextFieldsArray=[NSMutableArray array];
    int counter = 0 ;
    for (int i = 0; i <= pants - 2; i ++)
    {

        CGFloat x = counter * 1024;
        subView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, 1024, 693)];
        subView.clipsToBounds = NO;

        UIImage *img;
        UIImage *img2;


        img = [imgs objectAtIndex:i];
        img2 = [imgs objectAtIndex:i+1];


        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc ] initWithImage:img];
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(i * 512, 0, 512, 693);
        imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc ] initWithImage:img2];
        imageView2.frame = CGRectMake((i+1) * 512, 0, 512, 693);

///////////// ///////////// ///////////// TextViews Created///////////// ///////////// 
        rightTextView = [[UITextView alloc]init];
        leftTextView = [[UITextView alloc]init];

        rightTextView.scrollEnabled = YES;
        leftTextView.scrollEnabled = YES;
        rightTextView.editable = NO;
            leftTextView.editable = NO;
//////////////////////////////Specific Behavior regarding positioning in each view//////////

        if(i == 4) {
            leftTextView.frame = CGRectMake(2048, 0, 500,300);
        }
        else if(i == 6){
            leftTextView.frame = CGRectMake(3072, 450, 500,300);
            rightTextView.frame = CGRectMake(3584, 0, 500,200);
            rightTextView.layer.zPosition = 2;
        }
        else if(i==8){
            leftTextView.frame = CGRectMake(4096, 0, 500,300);
            rightTextView.frame = CGRectMake(4608, 450, 500,300);
        rightTextView.layer.zPosition = 2;
        }
        else if(i==10){
            leftTextView.frame = CGRectMake(5120, 0, 500,300);
            rightTextView.frame = CGRectMake(5632, 0, 500,300);
            rightTextView.layer.zPosition = 2;
        }
        else if(i==12){
            leftTextView.frame = CGRectMake(6144, 0, 500,300);
            rightTextView.frame = CGRectMake(6656, 450, 500,300);
            rightTextView.layer.zPosition = 2;
        }
        else if(i==14) {
            leftTextView.frame = CGRectMake(7168, 450, 500,300);
            rightTextView.frame = CGRectMake(7680, 0, 500,300);
            rightTextView.layer.zPosition = 2;

        }

        else if(i==16) {
            leftTextView.frame = CGRectMake(8192, 0, 500,300);
            rightTextView.frame = CGRectMake(8674, 0, 500,300);
            rightTextView.layer.zPosition = 2;
        }
        else if(i==18){
            leftTextView.frame = CGRectMake(9216, 450, 500,300);
            rightTextView.frame = CGRectMake(9728, 0, 500,300);
            rightTextView.layer.zPosition = 2;

        }
        else if(i==20){
            leftTextView.frame = CGRectMake(10240, 450, 500,300);
            rightTextView.frame = CGRectMake(10752, 450, 500,300);
            rightTextView.layer.zPosition = 2;
        }
        else if(i==22){
            leftTextView.frame = CGRectMake(11264, 0, 500,300);
            rightTextView.frame = CGRectMake(11776, 0, 500,300);
            rightTextView.layer.zPosition = 2;
        }
        rightTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        rightTextView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        rightTextView.text = rightArray[i/2];

        [rightTextFieldsArray addObject:rightTextView];

            leftTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            leftTextView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

            leftTextView.text = leftArray[i/2];

            [leftTextFieldsArray addObject:leftTextView];


        subView.scrollEnabled = NO;

        subView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;


        [subView addSubview:imageView];

        [imageView2 removeFromSuperview];

        [subView addSubview:leftTextView];

        [self.scroll1 addSubview:rightTextView];
        [self.scroll1 addSubview:subView];



    }



    counter ++;
    [super viewDidLoad];
  }
```

And i tried this method in my Button :

```
- (IBAction)increaseFontFun:(id)sender {
    [leftTextView setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:24.0f]];
}
```

So nothing happened no result. How can i achieve my purpose ? Many thanks

Comment: In the button method, have you checked that leftTextView is not nil? Put an `NSLog(@"%@",leftTextView);` in the method and see what result you get

Comment: @Flexicoder Thank you for ur reply, i tried it and this is what i get:  <UITextView: 0x7fd55401b800; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = '

         '; clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fd553643e30>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd553643d60>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {0, 30}>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code that you provided, in `increaseFontFun:` `leftTextView` will have a reference to the last `UItextView` that was created in the `viewDidLoad` method. 
I am not sure if I understand correctly but if you want all the UITextViews' font size to change you should loop through the `leftTextFieldsArray` and set the font for each one, or use NSArray's method `makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:`

Here is a sample

```
for(UITextView * textView in leftTextFieldsArray){
    textView.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, yes i do need all the textViews to change font.. i will try your suggestion now

Comment: Can you provide more details concerning that matter? i would highly appreciate it

Comment: Couldn't thank you enough it worked like a charm ! i edited the syntax error please accept it so for future reference it would be clear thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do This It's Very Simple:

```
UITextField *field = [[UITextField alloc] init];
field.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:50.0f];
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, please re-read my question because what your answer does not cover my situation

Answer (score 0):

Your code....

```
    leftTextView = [[UITextView alloc]init];

    rightTextView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    leftTextView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    rightTextView.editable = NO;
        leftTextView.editable = NO;

    if(i == 4) {
        leftTextView.frame = CGRectMake(2048, 0, 500,300);
    }
    else if(i == 6){
        leftTextView.frame = CGRectMake(3072, 450, 500,300);
        rightTextView.frame = CGRectMake(3584, 0, 500,200);
        rightTextView.layer.zPosition = 2;
    }

    ......
```

From the NSLog you've put in place the frame for the textview is 0,0,0,0 and therefore can't be seen. You need to add some initialisation that covers the fact that `i` might not be one of the values you are expecting